# Angular object undefined in one component, but not another how do I synch the two compontents

Tags: angular

I have a nav component, a login component and a service that call the db for the login to check if there is a matching username and password.

I have the service console.log the json that is returned. However, when I want to use the json in the nav component to hide some of the nav elements, along with show the username, then nav component says the object is undefined. Yet, right after the console.log() tells me it is undefined, it shows the json object written by the services console.log().

How can I synch the two components?

The following is the login component:

```
import { ShoppingCartValuesService } from "../shopping-cart-values.service";
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  public Obj: any;
  email = "";
  password = "";
  constructor(private srvc: ShoppingCartValuesService) {}

  login() {
    this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password);
    this.Obj = this.srvc.loginObj;
    console.log("this obj returned: " + this.Obj);
  }
}
```

this.Obj is undefined

The following is the services:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ShoppingCartValuesService {
  public shoppingCartValues = "n";
  public loginObj: any;
  public uri = "http://local.kronus:8001/v2018/assets/api/send_get.pdo.php";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  getLogin(email, password) {
    this.http
      .get(this.uri + "?name=" + email + "&pass1=" + password)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.loginObj = res;
        if (this.loginObj.isAdmin === "1") {
          console.log(this.loginObj);
        } else {
          console.log("this is not an admin account");
        }
        return this.loginObj;
        // this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      });
  }
}
```

The this.loginObj writes to the console.log() just fine

The ultimate goal is to use something like an *ngif="isAdmin" from the this.loginObj.isAdmin to show or hide parts of the nav

The following is my nav component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ShoppingCartValuesService } from "../shopping-cart-values.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-bs-navbar",
  templateUrl: "./bs-navbar.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./bs-navbar.component.css"]
})
export class BsNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  public loginObj: any;
  constructor(private srvc: ShoppingCartValuesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginObj = this.srvc.loginObj;
    console.log("isAdmin: " + this.loginObj.isAdmin);
  }
}
```

I am pretty sure that the reason why the this.loginObj.isAdmin is not working here, is because it is called at ngOnInit. Is there a lifecycle function to use for after the button has been clicked in the form?

The following is the login component html form:

```
  <div class="signup-form">
  <h2>Register</h2>
  <p class="hint-text">Login to your account.</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="email"
      class="form-control"
      name="email"
      placeholder="Email"
      required="required"
      [(ngModel)]="email"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input
      type="password"
      class="form-control"
      name="password"
      placeholder="Password"
      required="required"
      [(ngModel)]="password"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button (click)="login()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">
      Login
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    Need an account? <a routerLink="/register">Register here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for  your login page,

```
login() {
    this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password);
    this.Obj = this.srvc.loginObj;
    console.log("this obj returned: " + this.Obj);
  }
```

this.obj and console don't wait until you getLogin is done, so one suggesting solution
you should first: in your service:

```
 getLogin(email, password) {
    return new Observable((observe) => {
        this.http
          .get(this.uri + "?name=" + email + "&pass1=" + password)
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.loginObj = res;
            if (this.loginObj.isAdmin === "1") {
              console.log(this.loginObj);
            } else {
              console.log("this is not an admin account");
            }
            observe.next(res);
          });
        });
      }
```

======================================

in your login page

```
login() {
    this.srvc.getLogin(this.email, this.password).subscribe((result)=>{
       this.Obj = result;
       console.log("this obj returned: " , this.Obj);
     });
```

}

Comment: Thank you @Bassam, I am now seeing "this obj returned: [object Object]" in the console. Is this because once I make something observable, then I can subscribe to it? I tried making getLogin subscribe before, but I kept receiving interpolation errors. Once again, thank you for that. Can I ask you to please modify your answer to show me how to use the [object Object] and put this.Obj.isAdmin to show or hide parts of the nav component? Thank you sir

Comment: I was able to see the contents of this.Obj in the console, by using a comma instead of the "+" sign - console.log("this obj returned: ", this.Obj);

Comment: @kronus I have updated my answer, only I changed  '+' by comma.